# Concatenate text with numbers in a function with variable number of parameters

Tags: c, type-conversion, variadic-functions

I made a function in C, that concatenates a variable number of strings.
That's my code:

```
char* texto(const char* s, ...){
        va_list args;
        char *tmp;
        char *res;
        size_t len = strlen(s);

        // pega um handle ao início da lista de parâmetros
        va_start(args, s);
        // calcula o tamanho total de todas as strings - pega o próximo parâmetro da lista, até chegar no NULL
        while ((tmp = va_arg(args, char*))){
            len += strlen(tmp);
        }
        va_end(args);

        res = malloc(len+1);
        if (!res){
                fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao alocar string. Função 'texto'\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // cria a string concatenada
        strcpy(res, s);

        va_start(args, s);
        // pega o próximo parâmetro da lista, até chegar no NULL
        while ((tmp  = va_arg(args, char*))){ 
            strcat(res, tmp); 
        }
        va_end(args);

        return res;
}
```

I'm using like this:

```
char* txt = texto("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", NULL);
//txt is now: "abcde"
```

It works fine.
But I can't pass numeric parameters to this function, only strings.
I need to change the function to work like this:

```
char* txt = texto("a", "b", 1, "d", 4.5, "e", NULL);
//txt is now: "ab1d4.5e"
```

How can I do that?
How I get parameters with diferent types using va_arg()?

The solution I found until now is create a function int2str():

```
inline char* int2str(int inteiro){
    char* str = malloc(10);
    sprintf(str, "%d", inteiro);
    return str;
}
```

But I have to use this way:

```
char* txtnum = int2str(23);
char* txt = texto("a", txtnum, NULL);
free(txtnum);
```

otherwise, I got a memory leak...

I could use the function int2str() inside the function texto() but I don't know how to check the type of the parameters!

Ps.: I'm using C, not C++ for my code.

Comment: "Ps.: I'm using C, not C++ for my code."

Be aware, that `inline` is a C++ keyword, and not a C keyword.

Comment: Would a gcc specific solution be acceptable?

Comment: @Constantinius - I thought C99 added `inline` too?

Comment: @awoodland: sorry, you are right, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to take a gcc specific solution you can change `int2str` to be this macro:

```
# define int2str(i)                                                           \
  (__extension__                                                              \
    ({                                                                        \
      char *new = (char *) __builtin_alloca (10);                        \
      sprintf(new, "%d", i); \
      new;                                  \
    }))
```

This then means you can write:

```
char* txt = texto("a", int2str(23), NULL);
```

without leaking. It's *very* non portable though.

Comment: thanks @awoodland! with this code I can keep my actual code with no problems!
I'll look for this "__extension__" to know how it works, so maybe I can find a generic solution.
Tnks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do that? How I get parameters with diferent types using va_arg()?

Unfortunately this is not possible, the type information gets lost when you are using variable argument lists.

One quite easy solution is to use a format string which declares the "types", but then again, why don't you simply use the standard function `snprintf`? [Reference here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

```
char buffer[256];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s%s%d%s%f%s", "a", "b", 1, "d", 4.5, "e", NULL);
```

Comment: thanks @Constantinius, snprintf will solve my problem.
but I'm looking for a solution that a could use later, a function that returns a string. just like that.
so I dont need to worry about using extra variables or free()...